# this android app works in API 22 emulator not but in API 16 emulator

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie to android development. I am making a simple app to open camera in sufaceView. I want to work this app from the android API level 16. I have written some code and that works in API level 22 emulator but not in API level 16 emulator (When I click on Start button, app crashes)

> VideoServer.java
>
> ```
> package com.example.admin2.cameraonsurfaceview;
>
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.hardware.Camera;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
> import android.view.SurfaceView;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
> public class VideoServer extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
>     TextView testView;
>
>     Camera camera;
>     SurfaceView surfaceView;
>     SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
>
>     private final String tag = "VideoServer";
>
>     Button start, stop;
>
>     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>         start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
>         start.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
>             public void onClick(View arg0) {
>                 start_camera();
>             }
>         });
>
>         stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
>         stop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
>             public void onClick(View arg0) {
>                 stop_camera();
>             }
>         });
>
>         surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
>         surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
>         surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
>         surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
>
>         Toast.makeText(this, "Need your location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>
>
>
>     }
>
>     private void start_camera() {
>         try{
>             camera = Camera.open();
>         }catch(RuntimeException e){
>             Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
>             return;
>         }
>         Camera.Parameters param;
>         param = camera.getParameters();
>         //modify parameter
>         param.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
>         param.setPreviewSize(176, 144);
>         camera.setParameters(param);
>         try {
>             camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
>             camera.startPreview();
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
>             return;
>         }
>     }
>
>     private void stop_camera() {
>         camera.stopPreview();
>         camera.release();
>     }
>
>     public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     }
>
>     public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     }
>
>     public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     }
> }
> ```

and the layout file look like

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     tools:context="com.example.admin2.cameraonsurfaceview.MainActivity">
>
>     <SurfaceView
>         android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
>         android:layout_width="201dp"
>         android:layout_height="230dp"
>         tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
>         tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
>         android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
>         android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
>         tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
>         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btn_start"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Start"
>         android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/surfaceView1"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
>         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginStart="52dp" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btn_stop"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Stop"
>         tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
>         tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
>         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="131dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/surfaceView1"
>         app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.157" />
> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

My android manifest looks like

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="com.example.admin2.cameraonsurfaceview">
>
>     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
>
>     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
>
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>         android:supportsRtl="true"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>         <activity android:name=".VideoServer">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>     </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

when I click on the start button, app stops and I get the following exception

```
10-05 15:39:48.174 2335-2335/com.example.admin2.cameraonsurfaceview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.example.admin2.cameraonsurfaceview.VideoServer.start_camera(VideoServer.java:61)
  at com.example.admin2.cameraonsurfaceview.VideoServer.access$000(VideoServer.java:14)
  at com.example.admin2.cameraonsurfaceview.VideoServer$1.onClick(VideoServer.java:34)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How does it "not work"? Are you getting error messages, or is the app behaving different to your expectations? Please include those details in your question.

Comment: When I click on Start button, app crashes

Comment: Is this because I am not extending AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: See "[Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)"

Comment: @Joyal share logcat

Comment: @ModularSynth thanks

Comment: I added the log I get when I click on the camera start button, please help, thanks for your replies

Comment: See [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue myself.
The following line of code was causing the NullPointerException

> camera = Camera.open();

I changed to

> camera = Camera.open(1);

then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />` from your manifest.

Then check your version into `build.gradle`. Example:

`android { 
    defaultConfig { 
        minSdkVersion 16       // here you need to change into 16 if you already didn't
        targetSdkVersion 25
             .
             .`

In order to work on API 16 you need to set `minSdkVersion` to `16`. Then resync gradle and solve the problems that may appear with code that is not compatible with version 16.

Comment: its already like this. I added the log I get when I click on the camera start button, please help, thanks for your replies

Comment: Use debug and see what's null into `start_camera` method and see what's happening.